# Cout giving a weird output

Tags: c++, linux, output, cout

This is for a lab I have done, which is to create a simple queue using C++.

```
#include "Task5.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void push(const long &i, node* &n) {
    if (n == NULL) {
        node *ptr = new node;
        ptr -> item = i;
        ptr -> next = NULL;
        n = ptr;
        cout << "Created New Node." << endl;
    }
    else {
        node *ptr = n;
        cout << "Created Pointer" << endl;
        while (ptr -> next != NULL){
            cout << "Finding Next..." << endl;
            ptr = ptr -> next;
        }
        cout << "I'm here." << endl;
        node *temp = new node;
        temp -> item = i;
        ptr -> next = temp;
        cout << "Node Created." << endl;
    }
}

long pop(node* &n) {
    if (n == NULL) cout << "HEY!!! Can't pop an empty queue." << endl;
    else {
        long val;
        node *ptr = n;
        n = n -> next;
        val = ptr -> item;
        delete ptr;
        return val;
    }
}

int main() {
    node *head = NULL;
    push(13,head);
    push(10,head);
    push(18,head);
    push(22,head);
    cout << pop(head) << endl;
    cout << pop(head) << endl;
    cout << pop(head) << endl;
    cout << pop(head) << endl;
    cout << pop(head) << endl;
    cout << pop(head) << endl;
}
```

This is giving the following output:

> ```
> Created New Node.
> Created Pointer
> I'm Here.
> Node Created.
> Created Pointer
> Finding Next...
> I'm here.
> Node Created.
> Created Pointer
> Finding Next...
> Finding Next...
> I'm here.
> Node Created.
> 13
> 10
> 18
> 22
> HEY!!! Can't pop an empty queue.
> 6296192
> HEY!!! Can't pop an empty queue.
> 6296192
> ```

So the end result is that the code works, HOWEVER it outputs 6296192 randomly. I thought maybe I misspell something or cout is converting endl; to hex. My lab instructor also has no idea what's happening. Can someone tell me what is happening? If it helps, I am running this code via Linux-run terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Q: What value does pop() return when you try to pop an empty queue?

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings and/or stop ignoring the warning that tells you something to the effect that "not all control paths return a value" in your `pop` function. That would have been the first clue something may be wrong there. I hope the  "lab instructor also has no idea", isn't actually true ,and they *did* know but wanted you to find it on your own. If not, take nearly everything they give you for what it's worth (which likely won't be much).

Comment: @NathanOliver by virtue of the undecidability of the halting problem, it does.

Comment: @Quentin I removed the comment as I realized only a warning is raised here.  I do not think this is related to the halting problem as it is each to check if all exit paths return.

Comment: @NathanOliver that was overcomplicated. Just determining whether `foo() { bar(); }` should trigger the warning requires knowing whether `bar` halts.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Figured it out. Forgot to return something if empty stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function:

```
long pop(node* &n) {
```

you don't return anything in case of `n == NULL` is true. So this is UB, and might also cause such random values in output.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks. I knew it was something stupid XD

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the debugger with a breakpoint on the first `cout << pop(head) << endl;` and watch the value returned from pop each time.

Also the compiler is probably giving you a warning about the cause of the issue, always pay attention to the warnings it usually means something unintended will happen.

The `cout << pop(head) << endl;` uses the value returned by `pop()` but in the case of an empty queue there is no value returned, resulting in undefined behavior.